# ValueError: malformed node or string with ast.literal_eval() when adding a Keras layer

Tags: python, keras, valueerror

I want to build a Keras Model evaluating strings. If I do the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=10, input_shape=(10,), activation='softmax'))
```

It works fine. And I can see the `model.summary()`.

But, when I add the layer with `ast.literal_eval()`

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import ast

model = Sequential()
code = "model.add( Dense( input_shape=(10,), units=10, activation='softmax' ) )"
ast.literal_eval(code)
```

It throws me the next `ValueError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7efc40c90e10>
```

If I use `eval` instead of `ast.literal_eval` it works too.

I'm using python3.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A big mistake: `literal_eval` only works for **literals**. In this case, I have a **Call**.

The function `literal_eval` first parse the string.

**From /usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py: lines 38-46**

```
def literal_eval(node_or_string):
    """
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,
    sets, booleans, and None.
    """
    if isinstance(node_or_string, str):
        node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
```

At this point, `node_or_string` is an instance of `Expression`. Then, `literal_eval` get the body.

**From /usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py: lines 47-48**

```
    if isinstance(node_or_string, Expression):
        node_or_string = node_or_string.body
```

And finally, `literal_eval` checks the type of the body (`node_or_string`).

**From /usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py: lines 49-84**

```
    def _convert(node):
        if isinstance(node, (Str, Bytes)):
            return node.s
        elif isinstance(node, Num):
            return node.n
        elif isinstance(node, Tuple):
            return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, List):
            return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, Set):
            return set(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, Dict):
            return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
                        in zip(node.keys, node.values))
        elif isinstance(node, NameConstant):
            return node.value
        elif isinstance(node, UnaryOp) and \
             isinstance(node.op, (UAdd, USub)) and \
             isinstance(node.operand, (Num, UnaryOp, BinOp)):
            operand = _convert(node.operand)
            if isinstance(node.op, UAdd):
                return + operand
            else:
                return - operand
        elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and \
             isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)) and \
             isinstance(node.right, (Num, UnaryOp, BinOp)) and \
             isinstance(node.left, (Num, UnaryOp, BinOp)):
            left = _convert(node.left)
            right = _convert(node.right)
            if isinstance(node.op, Add):
                return left + right
            else:
                return left - right
        raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
    return _convert(node_or_string)
```

If the initial code was `ast.literal_eval('1+1')` (for example), now `node_or_string` would be an instance of `BinOp`. But in the case of:

```
code = "model.add( Dense( input_shape=(10,), units=10, activation='softmax' ) )"
ast.literal_eval(code)
```

The body will be an instance of `Call`, which does not appear among the valid types of the function.

E.g.:

```
import ast

code_nocall = "1+1"
node = ast.parse(code_nocall, mode='eval')
body = node.body
print(type(body)) # Returns <class '_ast.BinOp'>

code_call = "print('hello')"
node = ast.parse(code_call, mode='eval')
body = node.body
print(type(body)) # Returns <class '_ast.Call'>
```

## **Solution**

The best solution I have found so far, to not use `eval` directly, is to perform the process manually. With this function:

```
import ast

def eval_code(code):
    parsed = ast.parse(code, mode='eval')
    fixed = ast.fix_missing_locations(parsed)
    compiled = compile(fixed, '<string>', 'eval')
    eval(compiled)
```

Now it works:

```
eval_code("print('hello world')")

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
code = "model.add( Dense( input_shape=(10,), units=10, activation='softmax' ) )"
eval_code(code)
```