# How can we achieve the functionality like eval with ast.literal_eval

Tags: python

with `eval` I am able to get the below:

```
str1 = "23145"
str2 = "str1"
print(str2)
```

Output:

```
23145
```

working well and good.

with `ast.literal_eval`  that is not working as expected:

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(str2))
```

Getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/app/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 91, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/Volumes/app/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 90, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/Volumes/app/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/Volumes/app/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x10ce34190>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32695699/259889

Comment: First of all you don't actually use `eval` in the first example. Second, [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is only for, as its name suggests, literals, not names: *The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: malformed node or string with ast.literal\_eval() when adding a Keras layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711688/valueerror-malformed-node-or-string-with-ast-literal-eval-when-adding-a-keras)

Answer (score 0):

got the solution using globals().

```
str1 = “shiva”
str2 = “str1"
print(globals()[str2])
```

O/P: shiva